# Island paradise lag?

Tags: the-sims-3

I recently installed the island paradise expansion and whenever I play a sim on my island map the game lags and hangs every few seconds. My island town is the only map that lags like this.

What's causing this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely caused by **routing problems**.

To fix:

1. Download the [replacement .world for Isla Paradiso](http://modthesims.info/download.php?t=514909).
2. Follow the instructions (basically, find the original Isla Paradiso .world file, rename it, copy the downloaded .world to the same folder)
3. Fixes **affect only NEW games**; saved games on Isla Paradiso will *NOT* be fixed.
   If you're already attached to a family you're playing there, use a mod like [**NRaas Porter**](https://nraas.wikispaces.com/Porter) to export your family to the bin and restore in a NEW game.